# How do I display entries, grouped by distinct categories where the entries share a relationship to both the category and an entry in another channel

Tags: relations, templating

I have 2 channels:survivors, survivorContent and a Category:themes. Relationships are as follows:
survivorContent has -> related themes (max 3) AND survivorContent has -> related survivors (max 1)

Themes are always only one level deep.

I have a template that receives survivor.slug as a variable (based on a route). Given the survivor slug, I need to show a list of distinct themes that are *indirectly* related to this survivor (via the survivorContent->survivor relationship and the survivorContent->themes relationship). Then I need to show the survivorContent entries under each of those filtered themes that are related to both that theme and the given survivor to get output like this:

- Survivor.title
- - Related Theme 1
- - - Related survivorContent1 (related to both the Survivor & Theme 1)
- - - Related survivorContent2 (related to both the Survivor & Theme 1)
- - Related Theme 2
- - - Related survivorContent3 (related to both the Survivor & Theme 2)
- - - Related survivorContent1 (related to both the Survivor & Theme 2 as well as Theme 1, above)
- - etc...

I'm struggling to find a way to do this that is remotely efficient. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Set up a criteria model with both of your `relatedTo` conditions and add the hierarchy to the list of returned entries using Craft's `group` filter.

```
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries({
    section: 'survivorContent',
    relatedTo: [
        'and',
        {targetElement: entry.themesField},
        {targetElement: entry.survivorsField}
    ]
}) %}

{% set relatedEntriesGrouped = relatedEntries|group('themesField.first().title') %}

{% for title, entries in relatedEntriesGrouped %}
    {{ title }}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In case you don't have a "max. 1 element" limit set on your relationship fields, you might also want to look into something like the following.

```
{% for theme in entry.themesField %}

    {% set relatedEntries = craft.entries({
        section: 'survivorContent',
        relatedTo: [
            'and',
            {targetElement: theme},
            {targetElement: entry.survivorsField}
        ]
    }) %}

    {% if relatedEntries|length %}
        {{ theme.title }}
        {% for entries in relatedEntries %}
            {{ entry.title }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think your answer assumes the relationships originate at the survivor when actually, both relationships are from the survivorContent channel. That's what's messing me up. I edited my original question to clarify the relationships

Comment: Did you try the 2nd approach I posted? I think it could work for your use case.

Comment: If I use `entry` in a relatedTo param, I just get an error saying `Variable "entry" does not exist`