# Omitting current entry from list of entries generated from a relationship

Tags: entries, relations

On my template I am showing detail of an entry.
Beneath this I am showing a list of other entries that share the same kind of category relationship as the entry being viewed.

This list currently includes the entry being viewed and I wish to omit that from the list.

I'm retrieving the entries like so:

```
{% for category in craft.entries.section('apprenticeshipsCats').relatedTo(entry).id('not ' ~ entry.id) %}
```

and had expected the 'not' parameter to do what I wanted but it doesn't seem to be working. entry.id is outputting the correct ID and even if I hardcode the entry id then it still appears in the list.

Comment: Do you want to list entries from your "apprenticeships" or "apprenticeships categories" section?

Comment: I'm listing entries from the apprenticeships channel. It's all working fine except for being able to omit the apprenticeship entry which is currently viewed.

Comment: Ha! I'd actually done it correctly but applied by 'not' criteria to the wrong craft.entries loop. Like an idiot. I'm so amateur!

Comment: Like I said, wrong section. Compare the solution in your update to what I posted. You notice something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably kind of confuse your "apprenticeships categories" with your "apprenticeships" section. Try something like this instead:

```
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries({
    section: apprenticeships,
    id: 'not ' ~ entry.id,
    relatedTo: {
        targetElement: entry.apprenticeshipsCatsField
    }
}) %}
```

You now want to order them by your categories? Have a look at my answer I just posted here: ["How do I display entries, grouped by distinct categories..."](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/11944/125).

Comment: No. It was a different problem. Combined with a late night and rushing to get something done before I went out I was working with the wrong bit of the template. My original idea worked once I'd put it in the correct place.

Comment: Different problem? Changing "apprenticeshipsCats" to "apprenticeships" (or "vacancies" – I didn't know your channel handle) looks like exactly what you did in the end?!